# registerNib UiTableView not working after project corruption

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9, xcode7, nib

I am new to iOS. I have a cellForRowIndexPath implementation as follows

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListCell")
    if cell == nil {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "Cell",bundle : nil), forCellReuseIdentifier : "ListCell")
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListCell")
    }
    (cell as? Cell)?.label.text = data[indexPath.row].name
    return cell!
 }
```

This code was working initially. I accidentally did a git hard reset. The project files got all messed up. I fixed the other issues. In some cases by adding the files back again. 
But for some reason this piece of code is not working now. There is Cell.xib file in the project

**The error is 'Use of undeclared type Cell'** at

```
(cell as? Cell)?.label.text = data[indexPath.row].name
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you only need to register nib one time, so put this code in your `viewDidLoad` or tableView's `didSet`:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "Cell",bundle : nil), forCellReuseIdentifier : "ListCell")
```

In your `cellForRow`, change your code to:

```
var cell: Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListCell") as! Cell
cell.label.text = data[indexPath.row].name
return cell
```

You got error because you dont cast the default `UITableViewCell` to your custom `Cell`

Comment: I did as you suggested. Moved registerNib to viewDidLoad and cast it to Cell. But, now the line var cell: Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListCell") as! Cell shows error, says 'Use of undeclared type 'Cell'

Comment: Do you use custom cell?....If yes you have to create custom class for it

Comment: Thanks! Looks like after the project corruption Xcode lost reference of the file. Added it back again, now working :)